# How to show that for all $α, β \in Eq(X): α \circ β \subseteq α \vee β$?

Tags: equivalence-relations, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

I got this little algebra exercise which I am struggling with. My problem is probably that I am a beginner in working with relations and lattices, so I will appreciate any help.

Let $Eq(X)$ be the lattice of equivalence relations on a set $X$.

**The question:**

Show that for all $α, β \in Eq(X): α \circ β \subseteq α \vee β$, but that equality does not hold in general.

**My thoughts:**

Suppose $\langle a, b \rangle \in \alpha \circ \beta$. I will show that then it is also in $\alpha \vee \beta$. Then I will show that the opposite direction is not true.

LHS: By definition of the relational product, there is a $c \in X$ such that $\langle a, c \rangle \in \alpha$ **and** $\langle c, b \rangle \in \beta$. This is just a different notation for saying $a \: \alpha\:  c$ and $c\:\beta\: b$.

RHS: If $\langle a, b \rangle \in \alpha \lor \beta$ then there is a $c$ such that $\langle a, c \rangle \in \alpha$ **or** $\langle c, b \rangle \in \beta$.

This immediately shows that the RHS has a "weaker condition" or "subset of conditions" of the LHS, so if the LHS holds for something, it automatically holds for the RHS as well.

However, reversing the direction, If $\langle a, b \rangle \in \alpha \lor \beta$ then there is a $c$ such that $\langle a, c \rangle \in \alpha$ \textbf{or} $\langle c, b \rangle \in \beta$, but that does not imply that $\langle a, c \rangle \in \alpha$ \textbf{and} $\langle c, b \rangle \in \beta$. Therefore $\alpha \lor \beta \nsubseteq \alpha \circ \beta$.

Is this proof correct? I am not very sure and it seems suspiciously simple.

Any thoughts? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your definition of α ∨ β.  The correct definition is:

(x , y) ∈ α ∨ β  iff  ∃ n ∈ ℕ, ∃ c₀, c₁, …, cₙ such that x α c₀ β c₁ α ⋯ cₙ β y.

(See update below for alternative, equivalent definition.)

With the correct definition, the proof is straightforward.

By definition, (x , y) ∈ α ∘ β iff ∃ c such that x α c β y.

So take n = 0 and c₀ = c to see that (x , y) ∈ α ∨ β.

On the other hand, by concrete counterexample, you can show that α ∨ β ⊈ α ∘ β.

If you can't think of one on your own, play around with these equivalence relations on the set {0, 1, 2, 3}:

α = {(0, 0), (0,1), (1,0) (1,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,2), (3,3)}

β = {(0, 0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), (3,3)}

(and look at the pair (0,3))

**Update** As Adayah points out, an equivalent definition is that α ∨ β is the smallest equivalence relation containing α and β.

To solve the problem with this definition, suppose (x , y) ∈ α ∘ β.  Let c be such that x α c β y. Then, (x , c) ∈ α ⊆ α ∨ β and (c , y) ∈ β ⊆ α ∨ β.  Therefore, x (α ∨ β) c (α ∨ β) y, so by transitivity, (x , y) ∈ α ∨ β.

Comment: The correct definition of $\alpha \vee \beta$ is: the smallest equivalence relation containing both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Using your definition is basically like already assuming what we have to prove.

Comment: Haha, I think we are getting to the root problem, which I have even asked in a separate question, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278202/what-is-the-supremum-and-infimum-of-equivalence-relations/4278220?noredirect=1#comment8903932_4278220. Tbh I am still confused about the correct definition of $\alpha \lor \beta$.

Comment: @Adayah okay, but the definitions are equivalent, and the answer to this question using the "equivalence generated by α and β" definition is just as easy, so I'll leave my answer up for now, but update it to reflect your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @TerezaTizkova I looked at your other post.  It seems you are still thinking of the "join" symbol ∨ as logical "or."  In this context, ∨ means "least upper bound."  That is, α ∨ β denotes the least upper bound (in the lattice of equivalence relations) of the set {α, β}.  (In particular, x (α ∨ β) y does **not** mean ∃ c such that x α c **or** c β y.)

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo Thank you, I (hopefully) updated my thinking about this. But still, everyone tells what this ISN´T, however, noone stated the definition so far.

Comment: But I gave two alternative (equivalent) definitions of α ∨ β in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you, I have noticed now. I would say, that maybe, in the first definition, it wouldn´t matter whether the "chain" ends with $\beta$, or $\alpha$, but I am not sure.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova Yes, that's correct. The condition is that there exists some n (and c's) making the relation hold.  The sequence will end with α or β depending on whether n is even or odd.  Of course, once you find such a sequence, you could extend it with one more term (using reflexivity of α and β) if you want to ensure that it ends with a particular choice of α or β.