# What is the supremum and infimum of equivalence relations?

Tags: equivalence-relations, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

Suppose, I am working on $Eq(X)$ = the set of all equivalence relations on $X$. Let $\theta_1, \theta_2$ denote arbitrary equivalence relations.

Then how does $\theta_1 \lor \theta_2$ look like? And what about $\theta_1 \land \theta_2$?

I know lattices and that these usually correspond to supremum and infimum. But I cannot wrap my head around what does this mean for equivalence relations.

What does $\theta_1 \lor \theta_2$ mean for arbitrary $a, b \in \theta_1 \land \theta_2$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that an equivalence relation over $X$ is a subset of $X\times X$. In this case the order is containment.

The meet $\land$ is going to be the intersection as it usually works out. Note that the intersection of the relations is symmetric, transitive and reflexive.

The join $\lor$ is going to be be harder to describe, but it's essentially going to be the transitive closure of the union, since transitivity is the thing that can break when you take the union.

Comment: So does $a \: \theta_1 \lor \theta_2 \: b$ mean $a \: \theta_1 \: b$ or $a  \: \theta_2 \: b$?

Comment: No, $a\sim b$ under the equivalence relation $\theta_1 \lor \theta_2$ does not imply $a\sim b$ under relation $\theta_1$ or $a\sim b$ under relation $\theta_2$.  This is because $\theta_1 \lor \theta_2$ is not always the same as $\theta_1 \cup \theta _2$. Because the join is the transitive union of the closure, it  can have new relations that need to be added.

Comment: Basically your question is equivalent to asking if $\theta_1 \lor \theta_2$ is always the same as $\theta_1 \cup \theta_2$ and the answer is that not always.

Answer (score 0):

If we take two arbitrary elements $a, b$, how does $a (\theta_1 \lor \theta_2) b$ look like?

If this holds, there must exist an element $c$ such that

**$a \: \theta_1 \: c$ or $c \: \theta_2 \: b$.**                 (1)

Notice that this is not equivalent to

**$a \: \theta_1 \: b$ or $a \: \theta_2 \: b$**,                 (2)

since the join is not the same thing as union. If the union was a transitive relation, the (1) and (2) would be the same thing.

Comment: this isn't true either though, you can have a transitive closure that is longer than that. For example consider the equivalence relation  such that $2k\sim 2k+1$ over $\mathbb Z$ and the equivalence relation such that $2k+1 \sim 2k+2$. The join of these two equivalence relations is the one in which everything is equivalent, the transitive closure "closes arbitrarily long chains".

Comment: @Yorch I am simply interested in how does $a \: (\theta_1 \lor \theta_2) \: b$ look like. I still haven´t got any answer though.

Comment: What does it look like? well equivalence relations can be visualized as undirected graphs with clique components, the join is the transitive union of the graph with the union of both graph's edges, that's what it "looks like". But in any case that claim you are making in this post is false.

Comment: $\theta_1 \lor \theta_2$ is always a transitive relation by the way, because it is an element of the poset that you are working in, which consists of equivalence relations.

Comment: @Yorch No, I didn´t mean to vizualize, but rather what this tells about the elements. What other relations they have, given the said. I need to work with these relations and rewrite it somehow to solve my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277472/how-to-show-that-for-all-%ce%b1-%ce%b2-in-eqx-%ce%b1-circ-%ce%b2-subseteq-%ce%b1-vee-%ce%b2

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: They look like not very related problems to me

Comment: @Yorch Maybe I pasted wrong link before? Anyway, is even the first half of my answer true? I am pretty sure that the element $c$ exists with the properties I mentioned, I can even provide an academic source.

Comment: oh nevermind I made a mistake, yes that claim is true, although it is a very weak claim since you can always take $c=a$ regardless.